# SwiftUI AttributedString range not deselecting

Tags: swift, swiftui, syntax-highlighting, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am trying to write a simple ASCII Art Game Engine and for the sprite creation I wanted to test how to color text on button press. However I am quite frustrated by how it only works sometimes. Also I’m very new to UIViewRepresentable and don’t know how to fix it. What would also be good is like 3 or 4 different color buttons. Thanks in advance.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var attributedString = AttributedString("Hello, World!")
@State private var selectedRange: NSRange?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        AttributedTextEditor(text: $attributedString, selectedRange: $selectedRange)
        Button("Make it green!") {
            if let range = selectedRange {
                print(range)
                let greenText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(attributedString))
                greenText.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.green, range: range)
                attributedString = AttributedString(greenText)
            }
        }
    }
}
}


struct AttributedTextEditor: UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var text: AttributedString
@Binding var selectedRange: NSRange?

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.delegate = context.coordinator
    return textView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(text)
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    var parent: AttributedTextEditor
    
    init(_ parent: AttributedTextEditor) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
        parent.selectedRange = textView.selectedRange
    }
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        parent.selectedRange = nil
        parent.text = AttributedString(textView.attributedText)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me in my tests. However I get
 `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.`
 This could related to your issues.
 This warning is easily fixed using:
 `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.parent.selectedRange = textView.selectedRange }`
 in `AttributedTextEditor`.
 Try the fix, see if it works for you.

Comment: Still doesn’t work. Also the cursor jumps to the end after each update which is quite annoying.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there anything else other than "the cursor jumps to the end after each update"?

Comment: the words get marked green but sometimes when I edit the text it just continues to be green.

Comment: @KarlEhrlich You mean you want all the newly inserted text to be the default color? This is not how rich text editors usually work. Suppose I typed "helo", made it green, and then realised I forgot to type a second L. It would be very frustrating if I had to press the button to make it green *again*, after inserting the L in the middle.

Comment: no. sometimes when the word is already finished the text stays green.

Comment: Please show a *concrete* example of this. No one wants to *guess* whatever you mean.

Comment: @Sweeper Ok. For Example I type: Hello, World! then I highlight the word hello and press the button. the word gets green. I then do the same with word. however when I continue to type in the text editor not in the word but after everything, it gets green which I don't want.

Comment: Okay. This is just how rich text editors work. You can try the same thing on TextEdit on your mac, and it behaves in the same way. When you enter new text at the end of a "run" (a part of the text that has attributes), the "run" gets expanded. You'd need quite a lot of work to go against this design.